# You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '??_id)

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mithalim";
    String username = "root";
    String password = "1234";       
    try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password))
    {
        java.sql.Statement st = connection.createStatement();
        System.out.println("Database connected!");


        String query = "SELECT Patients.pastient_name as 'Pastient name', Queue_Reserved.queue_time AS Time FROM Patients "
                + "JOIN Queue_Reserved ON (Patients.pastient_id = Queue_Reserved.pastient‬‬_id) "
                + "WHERE Queue_Reserved.doctor_id=1 ORDER BY queue_time ASC";


        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);  

        System.out.println("test");
        java.sql.ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
        int columnsNumber = rsmd.getColumnCount();

        while (rs.next()) {
            for(int i = 1; i <= columnsNumber; i++)
                System.out.print(rs.getString(i) + " || ");
            System.out.println();
        }   
    } 

    catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot connect the database!", e);
    }
```

but I got this error :

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '??_id) WHERE Queue_Reserved.doctor_id=1 ORDER BY queue_time ASC' at line 1

Comment: `??_id) WHERE ...` think about it. And the error does not match your code.

Comment: You need to show your real code. The horrible code displayed would only show `Cannot connect the database!` for every exception. Also, as always, don't use `Statement`, use `PreparedStatement`.

Answer (score 1):

You have unprintable characters in your SQL.  It may *look* like your SQL contains this:

```
(Patients.pastient_id = Queue_Reserved.pastient_id)
```

But your code actually contains this Java string:

```
(Patients.pastient_id = Queue_Reserved.pastient\u202c\u202c_id)
```

The `\u202c` characters are unprintable [Pop Directional Formatting](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/202c/index.htm) characters.  Even if you set MySQL to use the right encoding (utf8mb4), your database table still wouldn’t have a column with that name.

Either use the ‘show unprintable characters’ function in your IDE or text editor, so you can delete those PDF characters, or delete `Queue_Reserved.pastient_id` and retype it directly (do not paste it from any other source).